# How to connect to a MQTT broker over SSL / TLS?

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am using [CloudMQTT](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/) as my hosted broker. Everything is working fine on plain MQTT, but when I tried to connect over TLS/SSL it is not working.

I found out that I need to specify the CA certificate files and path to work. 
On their [FAQ page](https://www.cloudmqtt.com/docs-faq.html#TLS_SSL) it says that their certificate files are available on most OSs (I am on Windows), but Windows doesn't store the certificates as files, so there is no path to it. I am stuck here. Which files to use?

Anyways I tried this command to subscribe over TLS/SSL (as said in their example)

```
mosquitto_sub -h [server] -t hello -p 2XXXX -u [username] -P [password] -d --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

It says this

```
Warning: Unable to open socket pair, outgoing publish commands may be delayed.
Client mosqsub/3740-Jem-PC sending CONNECT
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

I also changed the capath and cafile on the mosquitto.conf file.